# How to remove an extension that is blocking manage categories

Tags: category, extensions, magento-connect-manager

After clicking manage categories in the back end of magento
I have received this:

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Source model "mageplaza_seo/source_robots" not found for attribute "meta_robots"
>
> Trace:
>   #0 /home/tapisdor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "m...')
>
> Error log record number: 1450270382448

I understand it has to do with an extension that I have removed. But if I removed it on magento connect manager, why is this showing up?

Answer (score 1):

This extension have create an attribute `meta_robots` which   Source model model was exits at system.

As you have removed this attribute that this attribute does not find it Source Model.

So,you **need to delete this attribute** from `eav_attribute`  table from data table using below code

> ```
> delete from eav_attribute where attribute_code='meta_robots'
> ```

Also you remove those code which  call this attribute

Comment: Hi how  do I delete it on the back end of magento from table without using code?  since i do not have access to code.

Comment: run this code at mysql database of  your magento instance

Comment: Thanks  lot Amit for helping @SamA  I felt sad when my solution did't worked for him. Now i am sure he will get solution :- )

Comment: Is the database name mg_catalog_eav_attribute?

Answer (score 0):

if you dont required the attribute : `meta_robots` , just delete it and check the problem is still there or not

Comment: I delete it under  Catalog-attributes-manage attributes. The result was: There has been an error processing your request
Source model "mageplaza_seo/source_robots" not found for attribute "meta_robots"

Trace:
#0 /home/tapisdor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Sour

Comment: Please help the problem is still there

Comment: check Amit answer.

Comment: Is the database name mg_catalog_eav_attribute?

Comment: @SamA you dont need to worry about which database. please take the backup of current database, than run this query :  `delete from eav_attribute where attribute_code='meta_robots'`

Comment: Here's the output of the query from the command line.
MariaDB [tapisdor_store]> delete from eav_attribute where attribute_code='meta_robots';
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'tapisdor_store.eav_attribute' doesn't exist
there is no table named eav_attribute in database

Comment: @SamA did you found solution ?

Answer (score 0):

go to admin Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes and delete "meta_robots" attribute. Any manipulation with code and MySql.

Comment: It looks like your answer is incomplete - what do you mean by "any manipulation with code and MySql"?